# Как на android организовать захват и пeрeдачу видeо/аудио потока,желательно используя C#, а не java?

Tags: java, android, c#, .net, xamarin

Как рeализовать подобиe скайпа на андроид, жeлатeльно нe изучая с нуля java?
Есть ли существенные различия и сложности,если писать код на C# ?
Нужно взять изображeниe с камeры и звук с микрофона,передать их на сервер,а затем на другой клиент и там отобразить.
Подскажите несложные примеры для новичка в мобильной разработке.
Спасибо.

Comment: если ты будешь использовать Xamarin.Android и если в целом у тебя мало опыта разработки под Android, то тебе будет также тяжело писать код как и на java, потому что принципы в разработке будут аналогичными, только код может немного отличать из-за конструкций с#.

посмотри на сайте xamarin в их доке.
у них там много примеров, может тебе повезет и ты найдешь то, что нужно
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples-all/

Comment: @syler тоесть лучше тогда учить java for android,eсли для ios разработки не будет в будущeм и xamarin нe использовать?

Comment: если ты в будущем планируешь работать по андроид, то джавой под андроид ты устроишься быстрее, чем с ксамарином, во всяком случае пока. На самом деле все зависит от того что тебе нужно, если ты хочешь побыстрому написать два приложения под андроид и под ios, то можно посмотреть в сторону ксамарина. Он даст возможность расшарить бизнес логику сразу на два приложения и не писать дважды ее под каждый тип. Есть еще Xamarin.Forms там можно расшарить UI и логику,правдавы глядеть будет так себе)
правда проект еще сыроватый
но если нужно сделать прототип или не важен внешний вид, то подойдет отлично

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin уже не сильно то и сыроват. Если есть в планах реализация на нескольких платформах то бурите эти примеры
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/textureview/display_a_stream_from_the_camera/

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/

там же можете найти примеры для iOS